# The pushforward of the inclusion of immersed hypersurface of a Riemannian manifold preserves orthogonality?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be an (oriented) Riemannian manifold with or without boundary, let $\iota_S:S\subseteq M$ be an immersed hypersurface with or without boundary, and let $\tilde{g}$ denote the induced metric on $S$. Let $(E_1, \cdots ,E_{n-1})$ be an (oriented) orthonormal frame for $S$. Fix $ p \in S$. Then the pushforward $\iota_{S*,p} : T_{p}S \to T_{\iota(p)=p}M$ sends $(E_1|_p, \cdots ,E_{n-1}|_p)$ to orthonormal elements $(\iota_{S*,p}(E_1|_p) , \cdots , \iota_{S*,p}(E_{n-1}|_p)$    in $T_{p}M$?

This question originates from the John Lee's Introduction to smooth manifold, Proposition 15.32 :

[image]
[image]

Here $\omega_{g}$ is the Riemannian volume form (p.389) Why the underlined statement is true? I think that more correct notation is, for $p\in S$,

$$ \omega_{g,\iota(p)=p}( N_p , \iota_{S*,p}E_1|_{p}, \cdots ,\iota_{S*,p}E_{n-1}|_{p}) $$
And $\iota_{S*,p}(E_1|_p) , \cdots , \iota_{S*,p}(E_{n-1}|_p)$ is orthonormal? If so, why?

Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you compute what their inner product is? This is a matter of unwinding definitions.

Comment: Yes. I think I misunderstood something. Thank you~ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\iota_S: S \hookrightarrow M$ is just the inclusion map.

The first underlined equality follows form the definition of interior multiplication. Its just that by definition, $\iota_{S*}(X) = X$ since, $\iota_{S,*}$ is induced by inclusion.

So, clearly, $\iota_{S*,p}(E_1|_p), \dots, \iota_{S*,p}(E_{n-1}|_p)$ is an orthonormal set.

The second equality follows from the fact that $\omega_g$ is a volume form and that $N, E_1, E_2, \dots, E_{n-1}$ is a local oriented frame.

Comment: O.K. Thank you~